# max_input_vars in php.ini not updating after change

Tags: php, mysql

To keep it clear I'll give as much info as I can to solve this issue.

I tried importing a database today and got the message that my `max_input_vars` was on `1000` and it needed to be upped in `php.ini`.

I changed it to many numbers starting from `2000` up to `10000`. But everytime I changed it it would not update the `max_input_vars` and would keep giving me the same error.

I tried restarting the server and looking around the internet but could not find a fix. I hope someone here can help me out with this problem.

Comment: Describe what you have and what you are trying to do. That directive is for `how many input variables may be accepted`.

Comment: i am trying to up the max_input_vars in php.ini to be able to upload bigger databases into phpmyadmin, atm its giving me the error message that my max_input_vars is 1000 and needs to be higher. when i try to up it in the designated file php.ini and restart my server nothing changes and the message keeps popping up

Comment: try this please: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-max-input-vars-directive-in-an-htaccess-file

Comment: as suggested in the link u send i added the line of code to the .htaccess file and still nothing is working

Comment: Improved formatting :)

Answer (score 19):

Three things you might have overlooked:

1. Check phpinfo(); to make sure you're editing the right php.ini file.
2. If you've never updated that parameter, it's probably commented out like this:

```
; max_input_vars = 1000
```

So make sure you remove this sneaky semicolon at the beginning of the line.

3. Don't forget to restart your web server.

Comment: I was having the same issue. The culprit for me was the semicolon which easily got overlooked. Thanks for the tip Gabriel :)

Comment: Life saver. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

Please check if PHP is running as a service (for example php-fpm). In my case I needed to run:

```
service php-fpm reload
```

Comment: or `systemctl restart php-fpm` if running systemd but the above should redirect to systemctl anyways

Comment: In my case I had to also add the php version
`sudo service php8.2-fpm reload`

Answer (score 0):

1. Run phpinfo().
2. Look at the table rows almost at the top of the page

   - "Loaded Configuration File"
   - "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"
   - "Additional .ini files parsed"

     and this one about 5 screens from the top
   - "user_ini.filename" (see [manual page](https://php.net/configuration.file.per-user))
3. Among these .ini files (specified in these rows of phpinfo() output), find containing "max_input_vars" (without quotation marks).

Think, analyze...

In my case it was a Docksal issue ["Can't override php.ini..."](https://github.com/docksal/service-cli/issues/21), I created the second file of these two...

- .docksal/etc/php/php.ini
- .docksal/etc/php/php-fpm.conf

...and got the desired max_input_vars value!

Answer (score -2):

Just remove the ';' symbol at the beginning in the the line you edit input vars in php.ini file,  then restart php services or reboot

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but your suggestion is already part of the top voted answer - "So make sure you remove this sneaky semicolon at the beginning of the line." Please take time to read the posted answers before adding your own.